# Heroku: Putting a file in the bin folder

Tags: python, linux, django, heroku

I am sorry if this is too basic of a question but I spent the whole morning unsuccessfully  figuring it out.

I want to use the Heroku Scheduler for a Django app, and as per their documentary, I am supposed to put the python file I wan't to be executed by the Scheduler in the bin/ folder on Heroku.

Now on my local copy of the project, where do I create the folder bin w.r.t. the project root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create it in the project root.

Comment: Thank you!

That's what I did, but I got confused about it because I locally put a test.py file into bin/ which contains print "hello world". AFAIK if everything is correct I should be able to call it using python manage.py test on the command line, but it returns "unknown command test"

Comment: @user695652: You can call it with `bin/test.py` from the Heroku command line. Django management commands are placed in modules as described at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands/